# need buttons to spread out dynamically according to screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-button, android-tablelayout

I am working on an app that originally had it's button layout configured statically. What happens now is that on wider screens (SIII, Note, Tablets etc.) the table layout remains the same size on all of them and doesn't "spead out" dynamically. How can this code be adjusted to accomplish this?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/stoolRelative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/stoolmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menustool" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stoolText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/stoolmenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/stoolmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/foodRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/foodmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menufood" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foodText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/foodmenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/foodmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/PainRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/painmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menupain" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/painText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/painmenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/painmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15px"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/moodRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moodmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menumood" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moodText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/moodmenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/moodmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/medsTakeRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/medstakemenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menumeds" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/medsTakeText"
                android:layout_width="70px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/medstakemenu"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/medstakemenu"
                android:layout_below="@+id/medstakemenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/medstakenmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/otherIssuesRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/othermenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menuother" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otherIssuesText"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/othermenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/otherissuesmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15px"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/historyRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/historymenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menuhistory" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/historyText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/historymenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:text="@string/historymenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/historyRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/academymenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menuacademy" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/academyText"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/academymenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/ibdacademymenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myPassPortRelative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mypassportmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/menupassport" >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myPassportTextUp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mypassportmenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/myibdpassportmenu"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>
            <!--
        <TextView 
        android:layout_below="@+id/myPassportTextUp"
        android:text="Passport" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/myPassportTextDown" 
        ></TextView>
            -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the current layout

[image: http://imgur.com/fHEFn1H]

As the screen gets wider, the table remains this exact size and the margin on either side increases. ideas?

Comment: It would be easier if you show a screenshot how it looks like and some drawing or similar how it should look like

Comment: I included a URL as my reputation is not high enough to add an image

Comment: And you want the icons to become larger or only the distance between them?

Comment: only the distance between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `TableRow` change/add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

For each `RelativeLayout` change/add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help. I have to do a bit of editing, but this pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically(programmatically) adjust the positioning of your layout elements. For example, if we have 2 `TextViews` inside a `LinearLayout`, we can add a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `LinearLayout`:

```
myLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)
```

Inside this listener, we can access the width and the height of the layout elements. So, if we need to position our TextViews (spread them equally across the screen-width), we'll do the following:

```
int width = myLinearLayout.getWidth();
int lMarginTextView = (width - myTextView1.getWidth() - myTextView2.getWidth()) / 3;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsTV = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(     
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsTV.leftMargin = lMarginTextView;

myTextView1.setLayoutParams(paramsTV);
myTextView2.setLayoutParams(paramsTV);
```